# Stop JQuery script execution

Tags: jquery, loops, plugins, form-submit

I'm trying to code a tiny jquery plugin for my application. I've used `return false;` to stop the loop and its working.

I would like to stop the script at `return false;`  But the code still executes and calls `SubmitForm()` method.

```
$.fn.swiftSubmit = function (options) {
    $Form.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $('.validate').each(function(i, obj) {
            switch (dataType){
                case "string":
                    if(value==''){
                        return false; // want to stop here
                    }
                    break; 
            }
        });

        SubmitForm();
    });       
};
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The return false just getting you out of the each() scope. I trink you need an extra variable which you declare there and check it after the loop to return then.

Comment: @kmgt I think you are right.